# How to change a XML variable in android from a function outside the main fnction?

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView element called "textViewPuntuacion" in my .xml file in android. In my activity I have a function outside the main function that changes that element, but the problem is that it doesn´t change.

If I make this:

```
puntuacion=puntuacion+1;
textViewPuntuacion.setText("Puntuacion:"+puntuacion);
```

inside the main function, it works.

But if I do it in a function outside the main, it doesn´t work because if the function is called, the textView doen´t change. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: When you say: "main function" what do you mean? Can you add the function code to the question?

Comment: @gioravered I meant the onCreate function sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you step by step

`step 1` : first of all you need to declare your textView on the onCreate function

`step 2` : after findViewById just call the function name that you want to perform for increment value

`step 3` : On the button click you need to add that function call

step 4 : This is the function of your's

```
puntuacion++;
textViewPuntuacion.setText("Puntuacion:"+puntuacion);
```

It's works perfect ):